# MUI 5's AutoComplete doesn't allow the selected tags to be read out by a screenreader

Tags: javascript, html, material-ui, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a fairly standard use of AutoComplete, it's the same as the [Fixed Options example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#fixed-options). When I run NVDA and tab into it, it doesn't read out the already selected tags (in the above case 'Pulp fiction' and 'Incepton').

I can add an id to the tags with `renderTags` and I've tried to add an `aria-describedby` to both with `componentProps={{paper: {'aria-describedby':'id-of-tag1 id-of-tag2'}}}` and/or via the `renderInput` but I haven't got anything to even appear in the source, let alone read out the pre-selected tags.

What am I missing, or is this not possible?